# Set a column in numpy array to zero

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to set a column in numpy array to zero at different times, in other words, I have numpy array `M` with size 5000x500. When I enter shape command the result is (5000,500), I think 5000 are rows and 500 are columns

```
shape(M)
(5000,500)
```

But the problem when I want to access one column like first column

```
Mcol=M[:][0]
```

Then I check by shape again with new matrix `Mcol`

```
shape(Mcol)
(500,)
```

I expected the results will be (5000,) as the first has 5000 rows. Even when changed the operation the result was the same

```
shape(M)
(5000,500)
Mcol=M[0][:]
shape(Mcol)
(500,)
```

Any help please in explaining what happens in my code and if the following operation is right to set one column to zero

```
M[:][0]=0
```

Comment: What about doing M[:,0] = 0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
M[:][0] = 0
```

But you should be doing this:

```
M[:,0] = 0
```

The first one is wrong because `M[:]` just gives you the entire array, like `M`.  Then `[0]` gives you the first row.

Similarly, `M[0][:]` gives you the first row as well, because again `[:]` has no effect.

Comment: this answer doesn't actually answer the title of this question, only partially when combined with OPs post.